# How to have an image show up if a condition is met in Unity

Tags: image, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have three variable

None, TeamA, TeamB

I am just doing some debugging and would like for an image to appear, depending on which is selected.

Code used to select the crowd.

```
public enum crowdOptions {None, TeamA, TeamB};
public static crowdOptions CrowdOptions;

        if(Random.value < .33){
            CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.None;
        } else if (Random.value > .66){
            CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.TeamA;
        } else {
            CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.TeamB;
        }
```

I know I need to add it below the CrowdOptions, but I am not sure what the code is or how to connect it to the images.

I made UI Image box with a color; None = White, Team A = Red, Team B = Blue.

Here is the answer.  I needed to turn off the game object:

```
        if(Random.value < .33){
            CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.None;
            GameObject.Find("None").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =true;
            GameObject.Find("TeamA").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =false;
            GameObject.Find("TeamB").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =false;
        } else if (Random.value > .66){
            CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.TeamA;
            GameObject.Find("None").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =false;
            GameObject.Find("TeamA").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =true;
            GameObject.Find("TeamB").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =false;
        } else {
            CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.TeamB;
            GameObject.Find("TeamNone").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =false;
            GameObject.Find("TeamA").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =false;
            GameObject.Find("TeamB").GetComponent<Image>().enabled =true;
        }
```

Then name of the GameObjects  (images)  were None, TeamA, TeamB

Comment: Tim, your simplest approach would just be to "turn the game objects on and off" to make one or the other appear.  But it's almost impossible to answer such a broad question, what is an "image" ???  Do you mean you're using the UI system .. or what?

Comment: I did exactly what you said.  I had to think about it a bit I will update the code!

Comment: @TimCooley: Did you put the answer to your problem into your question? If so, could you take the answer part out of your question and post it as answer instead? This would then fit the structure of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim, your simplest approach would just be to "turn the game objects on and off" to make one or the other appear.

Just use `SetActive` to do this - read the manual or google for literally 1000s long tutorials on this.

I don't know why I'm doing this but here's more code tips

1) Choose a random ***INTEGER*** out of three and use that,

2) DON'T call for a random every time!  **choose it once** and use that value. this is a very basic mistake that can lead to huge bugs.

```
int r = Random.Range(0,3)
// means either 0,1 or 2
// READ MANUAL if you don't understand why
```

3) When you have to turn "one thing on" like that, a better plan is to **TURN THEM ALL OFF**, and then **TURN ONE ON**.  It's a more reliable, clear way to program.

```
void TurnAllOff()
 {
 teamA ... disabled
 teamB ... disabled
 teamC ... disabled
 }

void TurnOnOneRandomItem()
 {
 int r = Random.Range(0,2)
 TurnAllOff()
 if ( r == 0 ) teamA .. enabled
 if ( r == 1 ) teamB .. enabled
 if ( r == 2 ) teamC .. enabled
 }
```

You get it?

Notice how much easier it is now to, for example, add new values later, and how much easier it is to check your code is right.